# Как задать значение прогресс бара в каждом элементе ListView в коде?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите как сделать следующее:
имеется активити с автоматически заполняемым ListView

```
    private static final String NAMEFORM  = "NAMEFORM";
    private static final String DATEFORM = "DATEFORM";
    private static final String PROGRESS = "PROGRESS";
    private static final String PROGRMAX = "PROGRMAX";
    private static final String PROGRVAL = "PROGRVAL";
    private void createListPattern()
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> hm;
        myAcc = new ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>>();

        for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        {
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put(NAMEFORM,"форма"+String.valueOf(i));
            hm.put(DATEFORM,"дата сдачи"+String.valueOf(i));
            hm.put(PROGRESS,String.valueOf(i)+"/100");
            hm.put(PROGRMAX,100);//максимальное значение прогресс бара(возможно это делается не тут)
            hm.put(PROGRVAL,i*10);//текущее значение прогресс бара
            myAcc.add(hm);
        }
        //создаем адаптер для заполнения листа элементов
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
                myAcc,
                R.layout.select_pattern_elem, new String[]{
                NAMEFORM,
                DATEFORM,
                PROGRESS},
                new int[]{
                        R.id.textNamePattern,
                        R.id.textDate,
                        R.id.textProgress});
        //достаем  ListView 
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPattern);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    }
```

Каким образом мне в цикле, где я создаю хэшмап со значениями для других View, задать значения для прогресс бара?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком виде работать не будет, поскольку в `SimpleAdapter` массив идентификаторов `int[]`, как говорит документация принимает только идентификаторы от TextView:

> The views that should display column
> in the "from" parameter. These should
> all be TextViews. The first N views in
> this list are given the values of the
> first N columns in the from parameter.

Вам надо наследовать от `SimpleAdapter` создав собственный и далее в SimpleAdapter.getView() генерировать вьюшки в виде `ProgressBar`

Comment: это печально, может есть другой способ, проще

Comment: Создание собственного Adapter'а не такая сложная вещь (в большинстве случаев)

Comment: просто в моем случае нужно сделать, чтобы работало как для текстовых полей, так и для progressbar'a. Меня берут сомнения, что если я сделаю для для progressbar'a, то будет работать для TextView

Comment: А почему в цикле каждый раз новый конструктор для Map'а вызывается? Почему он не сработает для TextView (вы просто нужную вьюху инфлейтите)

Comment: потому что, каждый раз, создается новый элемент для ListView

Comment: Ну дак и отдавайте нужный View для элемента ListView